# Newbie to VSCode : GCC was already installed but VScode does not recognize and powershell terminal still blank

Tags: c, powershell, visual-studio-code, gcc

I am newbie to the VSCode, currently I would like to run C program debugging mode in VS code.
First I installed the C/C++ extension in VScode and then I install MingW in laptop and already define the environment path. Therefore, after installing MingW, I can check the gcc version in the command prompt.

```
gcc --version
```

> gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
> Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Then I wrote a simple C program in VScode

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<crtdbg.h>
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int* offset_x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int* offset_y = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (offset_x==NULL || offset_y == NULL)
    {
         return 1;
    }
    *offset_x =10;
    *offset_y = 20;
    free(offset_x);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Then when I open the new terminal which is powershell one, the terminal is totally blank one.
So I searched in google, and it is recommended to change "True" in terminal.integrated.inheritEnv at settings.json. Therefore the below commands are the one in my settings.json.

```
"workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true,
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {   
},
"terminal.integrated.automationShell.osx": "",
"terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "",
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": ""
```

After modifying this inheritEnv to true, I still got the same problem of the powershell terminal is still blank and cannot write anything.

---

Moreover, when I try to run the program in VSCode, I also got the message of gcc is not recognized.

> 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

> [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.693 seconds

Gcc is recognized when I checked in command prompt. But I don't know why it is not recognized in the VSCode and cannot debug the program.

To sum up,
I got 2 errors:

1. powershell Terminal is in blank and cannot type or enter anything.
2. Gcc is not recognized in VSCode even it is installed, defined the environment path and can check the gcc version in command prompt.

**May I know how can I solve those 2 problems?**

Moreover in VSCode Terminal, I found command prompt, powershell to choose.
I also would like to know what is the difference between using command prompt as a terminal and powershell as a terminal?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you done this step mentioned here - creating tasks.json? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_build-helloworldcpp

Comment: Thank you Kiner. After creating tasks.json, the issue was solved.